# JS code on Button

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

Hello Guys i have a little tricky question  regarding static resources. I have made a js code  and now i want to use this js code on the click event of a button ?My question is that  can we right this js code in static resources and from there can call this one on button by click event. If yes then Help me out

Comment: why don't you just set the behaviour of your button to execute javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can do this.

1) Make sure all the code that you want to execute onclick is encapsulated inside function. (This just for a simplification)

2) Add that file to the button definition using the {!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/yourjsfile')}`.

3) Change the property of the button to 'onClick javascript' and call the function defined in the js from the button.

So lets say you have file with all the code inside a function

```
function calledWhenClickedOnButton() {
   // all you code that you want to execute
}
```

Inside the button javascript definition you code will something like this:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/yourjavascriptFile')}
calledWhenClickedOnButton();
```

Another way to do it by adding an `eventListener` in the file itself so that whenever the button is clicked you can call your function.

Comment: it works .Thanx one more  help needed from your side. I want to user the google map on my detail page layout. how can we use this like my section is Location having street address and City How can we use this on the  custom object

Comment: We can definitely show Gmaps on detail page. I think its better to  post it as separate question so that you get better responses.